# ConcurrentModificationException using Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I'm using an iterator to loop over a collection as follows:

```
Iterator<Entity> entityItr = entityList.iterator(); 

    while (entityItr.hasNext())
    {
        Entity curr = entityItr.next();

        for (Component c : curr.getComponents())
        {
            if (c instanceof PlayerControlled)
            {
                ((PlayerControlled) c).pollKeyboard();  
            }
        }
    }
```

However on the following line I get a ConcurrentModificationException

```
 Entity curr = entityItr.next();
```

Why is this happening when I'm not altering anything?

Many thanks

Edit - stack trace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at cw.systems.Input.checkInputs(Input.java:31)
at cw.systems.Input.begin(Input.java:21)
at cw.misc.Game.render(Game.java:73)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Comment: The stack trace should explain it. Read it, and post it. The exception name and javadoc also explains it: you're modifying the collection while iterating on it.

Comment: Are you sure `pollKeyboard` cannot modify `entityList` somehow?

Comment: @SebastianRedl I think if `pollKeyboard` is modifying `entityList` somehow the Exception will be thrown from `((PlayerControlled) c).pollKeyboard();` not from `Entity curr = entityItr.next();` . right ?

Comment: A quick fix would be using `for(int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++)` to avoid this error

Comment: @EpicPandaForce This error is thrown to prevent more serious concurency problems which could be harder to find. What if you enter loop but before you will access element `i` some element before `i` was removed shifting other elements? You would end up skipping one element.

Comment: I switched to an iterator because I wanted to be able to alter a collection while iterating through it. Poll keyboard does edit the entity list, but the iterator is rebuilt again at the very top line so shouldn't this prevent that? Am I misunderstanding the iterator object?

Comment: Using an iterator allows you to modify a collection while iterating on it, as long as you use a method of the iterator to modify it. And no, the iterator is not rebuilt again. At each iteration, the same iterator object is used to get the next element.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat If `pollKeyboard` removes or adds to the list without using the iterator methods it won't throw an exception. Instead the iterator will throw an exception on the next operation.

Comment: @AndyBrown oh well, that's a new one I wasn't know, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be modifying the list either:

1. inside your iterator in the `pollKeyboard` method, without using the `add` or `remove` methods on the iterator; or
2. in another thread

Therefore your exception is the expected behaviour. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), if you have a single thread iterating the list:

> if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException

and if multiple threads uses the list at one time:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, **it must be synchronized externally**

#### Solution:

If only one thread accesses the list, make sure you use the [`entityItr.remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) or `add` methods to modify the list.

For the multi-threaded case you can use [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) if you do not have a locking object available.

First store a single central reference to your list as:

```
entityList = Collections.synchronizedList(theOriginalArrayList);
```

And then access it (with all readers and writers) as:

```
synchronized (entityList) {
  // Readers might do:
  itr = entityList.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext())
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

There are other ways to sync multi-threaded access, including copying the list to an array (inside a sync block) and iterating it for reading, or using a `ReadWrite` lock. They all depend on your exact requirement.

Comment: Having both a `synchronizedList` and a `synchronized` block seems like overkill.

Comment: @SebastianRedl . If you just want to call `add` you can do so directly on the returned list, but for iterators I'll quote [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) again: "*synchronizedList returns a  synchronized ... list. ... all access must be accomplished through the returned list ...* **It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it ... Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior**".

Comment: Having *just* a synchronized block around all access code is enough. That makes the additional wrapper indeed overkill.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `synchronizedList()` allows you to avoid the sync block when you aren't iterating as methods such as `add` do their own sync block under the covers. However you still use the sync block for iterating. Therefore as a general pattern you should use `synchronizedList()`, sync on it for iteration, and use the direct methods for other operations. Yes, if you have a different sync object and use that for all your code you can, but you must sync on every operation.

Comment: Sure. But the wider point is that `synchronizedList` is not able to enforce thread safety of its public API. In fact, you just get an even more complex contract: synchronize this, don't synchronize that, and be very careful not to inadvertently pass the list to a 3rd-party method which may happen to iterate over it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't see how using a sync block for all access helps with the "*be very careful not to inadvertently pass the list to a 3rd-party method which may happen to iterate over it*" - that would suggest a leaky design problem with the container class for the list in question. The rule "sync for iterate, use the wrapper methods otherwise" seems simple enough? (Hoping the discussion link will pop up on this comment thread in a minute).

Comment: I'm talking about *implementation code*, not leaky design. Again, the rule may sound simple, but in practice it's not as simple to follow. For example, just passing the list to an `ArrayList` constructor violates the rule quite subtly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69073/discussion-between-andy-brown-and-marko-topolnik).

Answer (score -1):

It looks that there is another thread using the same collection and modifing it when this code is iterating over the collection.

[ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

You can use navite java [concurrent collestions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html) instead. They are thread safe. However it's a good habbit to create [immutable collections](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) - they are thread safe and enforce you to design reliable code.